print mtime along with filename with find command and delete it
I have the below find command which finds all folder mtime greater than some age. I want to log mtime in machine-readable format along with file name and delete the folders as well. Any help on upgrading the find command would help.
find $path -depth 2 -type d -mtime +$days


Regarding along with file name, do you mean directory name?

Someting like?
find "$path" -depth 2 -type d -mtime +"$days" -exec sh -c 'for dir; do echo "$(stat -c %Y "$dir") $dir" >> deletion_log.txt; rm -rf "$dir"; done' sh {} +


tried above in MAC. I do not see date printed in log file

This worked on unix. Is there any way to get date in US format with time

you can extend the find command with the exec-option (sample for bash):
find "$path" -depth 2 -type d -mtime +$days -exec sh -c '
  for dir; do
    # Log the mtime and the directory name in a machine-readable format
    stat --format="%Y %n" "$dir" >> /path/to/logfile.log
    
    # Delete the directory after logging
    rm -rf "$dir"
  done
' sh {} +


Seeing error stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
when trying script in MAC

Also I do not see date printed, when tried from MAC

This worked on unix. Is there any way to get date in US format with time
